# Using Bash to sort all columns?

Tags: bash, sorting, io

I have an input file (limited to 2 records, # of columns is not limited) such as:

```
6 5 9 4.5 
3 9 13 1
```

and I would like to use a bash sort script that would sort every column in the file and produce output:

```
3 5 9 1
6 9 13 4.5
```

The purpose of this is that I want to compare and pull out only the largest in each column.

I figured sorting all columns and then just printing out the last record of the file would be a good solution to this, however I am having trouble finding code that will sort every column. Is it possible for bash to iterate through a 'for loop' as long as it does not reach EOF, and sort each column of the current field?

IMPORTANT NOTE ** There can be any numbers of columns, however only 2 records. **

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your numbers are in a file called `text` which looks like this

```
6 5 9 4.5
3 9 13 1
```

Where each number is delimited by a single space you can do this..

```
#array of all the numbers in the first line of text
num=($(head -n 1 text))

#array for each resulting line
row1=()
row2=()

#iterate num length times
for (( i=1; i<=${#num[@]}; ++i )); do

    #cut the ith column from the file and sort it
    col=($(cat text | cut -d ' ' -f$i | sort -n))

    #split column into its respective rows
    row1+=( ${col[0]} )
    row2+=( ${col[1]} )
done

#write results out to file
echo ${row1[@]} >> sorted_text
echo ${row2[@]} >> sorted_text
```

This will result in a file called `sorted_text` which will look like this

```
3 5 9 1
6 9 13 4.5
```

If you only want the line with the biggest numbers then remove `row1` from the output

Answer (score 0):

> The purpose of this is that I want to compare and pull out only the largest in each column.

In that case, assuming the input file is called `data`:

```
# Read the two lines into arrays:
{ read line1 ; read line2 ; } <data     
line1=($line1)
line2=($line2)
# Compare the two lines, finding the max for each column
out=
for ((i=0; i<${#line1[@]}; i++))
do
    max=${line1[$i]}
    [[ 1 = "$(echo "${line2[$i]} > ${line1[$i]}" | bc)" ]] && max=${line2[$i]}
    out="$out $max"
done
# Show results
echo $out
```

The above produces the output:

```
6 9 13 4.5
```

Comment: This results in.. "line 11: bc: command not found." Is there some syntax error preventing bc from being piped in correctly?

Comment: @Blued00d  To check on the possibility of a typo, I just copied the code from this answer back to my PC.  It ran without error. Is `bc` installed and working on your system?  For example, if you run `echo 4+6 | bc` at the command line, does it return 10?

Answer (score 0):

We can use this command

awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++); print}' | sort filename.txt